# jQuery drop down menu with images as parent LI's

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

So I want to use images in my parent [li] elements for my nav menu on my site, and would like to know what y'all think the best way of going about that is? I'm not asking for anything written out just an idea. I would like the child list items to have a white background and have a width of about 80 pixels. I thought of just putting the images within the list items before the anchor tags, but the images would be draggable and it would look cheap in my opinion.

I know I'll probably get flamed for this question, but even if its just a one sentence suggestion it would help as there doesn't seem to much on the net regarding drop down menus using images.

Sorry in advance if there is not enough detail :)

Comment: use CSS background-image property

Comment: ok that's what I thought, thanks. I just want to make everything as semantic as possible, wasn't sure if that was bad practice. Should I leave the anchor text blank and just insert the images via the anchor class/id or the list item?

Comment: i would set via the anchor class so that you can have a hover effect if need be as well. Also make sure they're block elements so they are fully clickable.

Comment: Damn, I didn't actually search before as I couldn't find anything with my particular google searches. For whatever reason, when I try to insert the image as a background it doesn't show up. I haven't built the nav menu yet, I was just testing the background property but it's not working .. any idea?

Comment: I made each anchor have the id of the image name, and wrote down #whatever with the property background:url('blah'); to no avail.

Comment: first of all, uses classes, and are you entering the correct URL? inspect the DOM to see if background-image is a valid resource.

Comment: Ok it works when using class but it didn't seem to work when I used an ID .. and why do you suggest using classes vs id? Thanks for the help so far

Comment: even though you're not using jQuery now, accessing classes in the DOM is less resource heavy then selecting by ID. Also, classes can act as a multiple flag/selector for different elements, which can be very useful when trying to target multiple elements. The one thing that IDs have are the hash value for the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When styling the parent `<li>` elements (also known as the first childs) you can specificly target them like this:

```
ul > li {
  background : url('../img/bg.jpg');
}
```

The best thing is that this won't target the `<li>` elements underneath the first `<li>`.

Comment: alright thanks but each first child li is going to have a different image so how I would I do that but with an id attatched? Sorry for these stupid questions.

Comment: There are no stupid questions. If you use an ID always use the ID only once in the page. Just add an ID to your list item.

Comment: alright, lastly when is it appropriate to use an id vs a class? I know you can use classes more than once, so would that be the only difference? (if you want to target multiple elements?)

Comment: Well keep in mind that you will only use these background images once. That means they are unique. And once elements need to be unique go for IDs :)